# Laravel NumberFormatter Output issue

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to convert total into words and it gives me a wrong output.

I have to pass this in
`{{$receipt_details->total}}` which is in
laravel blade template into words

Here is my code

```
@php
    $num = $receipt_details->total;
    $f = new NumberFormatter("en", NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
    echo $f->format($num);
@endphp
```

The output I get is Zero for all the totals.

Comment: Are you getting value in `$num = $receipt_details->total;`

Comment: yes, I am passing the value to $num

Comment: after @php can you echo $receipt_details->total; and tell us what the value is

Comment: I am getting the number perfectly